# Algorithm with two unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all, I am not familiar with mathematics.

I am trying to materialize an algorithm to solve a specific need.

Let's assume we have $3$ portions of $3$ different vegetables.

- 1 portion of courgettes weights $55$g (gramms)
- 1 portion of aubergines weights $110$g
- 1 portion of carrots weights $90$g

Now let's assume that I want to eat for $300$g of vegetables, but still have $3$ portions in total.

Can anyone help me figuring out an equation that can find all possible answers?

Here is what I know so far:

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3$
- $55\times x_1 + 110\times x_2 + 90\times x_3 = 300$

$x$ can be fractional numbers.

Comment: I don't think its possible for 300 grams exactly, do you mean > 300 grams? Or can you have decimal portions? Also if you remove the constraint of having exactly 3 portions, this is the knapsack problem which is NP-Complete.

Comment: You mean we can have fractional portions?

Comment: Can you please define "close to 300 grams"? That is a very relative term. I.e. Give a range of grams that are deemed 'acceptable', is 200 - 400 grams close, 100 to 500 grams close?

Comment: more or less 10%. Yes we can have fractional portions, and grams too.

Comment: However I believe that we can always find the exact 300g sum if both P and X can be fractional numbers.

Comment: That's right, but then you have 4 portions, we need to have 3 portions. Then I am wondering if $x$ and $p$ are not the same after all? I have edited the mai question to add some context. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I can do two full portions of aubergine, and $\frac {80}{110}$ of a third.  Or I can do two full portions of aubergine, and $\frac {80}{90}$ of a portion of carrots.  Is that the answer you wanted or were you looking for something else?

Comment: If you insist that the fractions add to $3$ then you can, say, let $x_1$=0, in which case the two equtions $x_2+x_3=3$ and $110x_2+90x_3=300$ resolve to $(x_2,x_3)=(1.5,1.5)$.  Is that more like what you wanted?

Comment: Yes lulu, your answer is one possibility to answer this problem, I want to be able to find all viable possibilities for this problem.

Comment: Ok, look at my posted solution below.  Does it do what you want?

Comment: Yes @lulu that's right, but $x$ must be strictly positive. Thanks!

Comment: So, fine:  the general solution is $0<x_1<\frac 67$, $x_2=\frac {6+7x_1}4$, $x_3=\frac {6-7x_1}4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:  the previous version of this contained an algebraic error.  This version is (hopefully) correct.

If you fix $x_1$ the two conditions become $$x_2+x_3=3-x_1\;\;\&\;\;110x_2+90x_3=300-55x_1$$

Solving then yields:  $$x_2=\frac {6+7x_1}{4}\;\;\&\;\;x_3=\frac {6-11x_1}4$$

To see this, rewrite the first of the two equations as $$90x_2+90x_3=270-90x_1$$  Now subtract this equation from the second of the two constraints to get $$20x_2=30+35x_1\implies 4x_2=6+7x_1\implies x_2=\frac {6+7x_1}4$$

To conclude, note that the first constraint tells us $$x_3=3-x_2-x_1=3-\frac {6+7x_1}4-x_1=\frac {12-6-7x_1-4x_1}4=\frac {6-11x_1}4$$

To ensure that these are all strictly positive, note that $x_1>0\implies x_2>0$ but $x_3>0\implies x_1<\frac 6{11}$, so we must have $0<x_1<\frac 6{11}$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I can't make this work though. Considering $x_1 = 0.5$ then $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3.5$ instead of $3$.

Comment: You're right.  I botched the (trivial) algebra.  I'll correct it now.

Comment: Try it now.  Taking $x_1=.5$ yields the solution $\{.5, 2.375,.125\}$ which seems acceptable.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @lulu!

Comment: It would be great if you could add the steps to solve the equation too! Thanks again.

Comment: Given that I botched the algebra on the first pass, seems the least I can do.  I'll edit now.